# Grouping cluster Google map API

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, google-maps-api-2

I am using the library for one of my project (https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils)

This library let me create cluster on the google map, but I was wondering if it is possible to cluster my marker by group. For example, I want to cluster only markers that are "Friends" and cluster the others who are only "Coworker" and etc... (Maybe not the best example, but I hope that you understand)

My idea was to use multiple ClusterManager but I didn't tried it and don't really know if it is the best solution or even a good solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution for my problem. The better solution is to manage multiple Clustermanagers  if you want to create multiple group.

By the way, all the credits for the answer goes to @Brody on the Github :

Here the link : https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/issues/100#event-153755438

Answer (score 0):

Using multiple `ClusterManager` is cumbersome. I think it is easier to use multiple `Algorithm` with a wrapper.

The wrapper should choose the correct algorithm according to the item properties. The only requirement is that all items must have a common parent class (`Item` in the example below).

```
public class MultiAlgorithm<T extends ClusterItem> implements Algorithm<T> {

    private final Algorithm<T> friendsAlgorithm;
    private final Algorithm<T> coworkerAlgorithm;

    public MultiAlgorithm() {
        friendsAlgorithm = new NonHierarchicalDistanceBasedAlgorithm<>();
        coworkerAlgorithm = new NonHierarchicalDistanceBasedAlgorithm<>();
    }

    private Algorithm<T> getAlgorithm(T item) {
        // TODO Return the correct algorithm based on 'item' properties
    }

    @Override
    public void addItem(T item) {
        getAlgorithm(item).addItem(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void addItems(Collection<T> collection) {
        for (T item : collection) {
            getAlgorithm(item).addItem(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void clearItems() {
        friendsAlgorithm.clearItems();
        coworkerAlgorithm.clearItems();
    }

    @Override
    public void removeItem(T item) {
        getAlgorithm(item).removeItem(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public Set<? extends Cluster<T>> getClusters(double zoom) {
        // Use a non-typed Set to prevent some generic issue on the result.addAll() method
        Set result = new HashSet<>(friendsAlgorithm.getClusters(zoom));
        result.addAll(coworkerAlgorithm.getClusters(zoom));
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<T> getItems() {
        Collection<T> result = new ArrayList<>(friendsAlgorithm.);
        result.addAll(coworkerAlgorithm.getItems());
        return result;
    }
}
```

Usage: `clusterManager.setAlgorithm(new MultiAlgorithm<Item>());`